# Как добавить еще один Resources.resx?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Всем привет. Делаю программу мультиязычной. В зависимости от выбранно языка хочу использовать свой Resources.resx. Вытягивать значения буду, к примеру, так 
`Properties.Resources.strNo`
По умолчанию один есть Resources, как добавить еще один для английского языка?

Comment: [Это?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa992030(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: ДА!!! Спасибо. Именно это.

Comment: Добавил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Практическое руководство. Создание локализованной версии файла ресурсов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa992030(v=vs.100).aspx)